# Selenium CaptureEntireScreenShot throws error in IE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to resolve this below issues while capture screen in IE?

I have registered the snapsie.dll in C:\Windows

Error Detail:

"Error: Snapsie failed: Is it installed? Does it have permission to run as an add-on? See http://snapsie.sourceforge.net/"

Comment: have you done what the error suggested?

Comment: Hi I have download the snapsie.dll from soundforge.net and copied into C:\windows directory and registered using regsvr32. And enable the activex control in IE browser. Still got the same issue. Any idea on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium CaptureEntirePageScreenshot fails in IE in selenium-server-standalone-2.5.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414633/selenium-captureentirepagescreenshot-fails-in-ie-in-selenium-server-standalone-2)